# How to define static ip on docker-compose v3

Tags: docker, docker-compose, microservices

I'm developing a microservice application with spring boot. While I'm devoloping microservice application, I'm using docker compose. I want to define static ip to my service. But when I define static ip, I'm getting an error.

I'm using version: '3.1' (docker-compose.yml). My error is written below. Where am I doing wrong

```
ERROR: for service-user  user specified IP address is supported only when connecting to networks with user configured subnets
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

My docker-compose.yml is

```
  service-user:
    container_name: "service-user"
    hostname: "service-user"
    build: ../../service-user/target
    ports:
      - "8809:8809"
    expose:
      - "8809"
    depends_on:
      - service-eureka
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=${profile}
    networks:
      backend:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.238.10
```

```
 networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.16.238.0/24
```

Comment: You shouldn't usually need this; the Compose service name `service-user` will be usable as a host name, as described in [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.  Is there a specific reason you're trying to set a static address?

Comment: (You should be able to delete `container_name:`, `hostname:`, `expose:`, and both `networks:` blocks without affecting your overall system.)

Comment: Hello, My problem solved but I won't do anything. I was only run "docker system prune" command. Than I was defined static ip. If problem will continue, I will try your advice. Thank you for comment